# Change Bootstrap JS Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following script:

```
$(".btn.btn-default").click(function () {
$(this).siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active').val($(this).text());
        if (this.id.contains('fear')) {
            $('#fear').val($(this).text());              
        } else if (this.id.contains('control')) {
            $('#control').val($(this).text());               
        } else if (this.id.contains('danger')) {
            $('#danger').val($(this).text());
            $('#tab2').tab('show');
        }
    });
```

Focusing specifically on when #danger is clicked, I'm trying to change the bootstrap tab with:

```
$('#tab2').tab('show');
```

however it does not seem to work. Any ideas?

//Updated with tab html

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Step 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Step 2</a></li>            
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div id="obj" class="draggable drag-drop"> Grass </div>
        <div id="obj" class="draggable drag-drop"> Tree </div>                    
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div id="act" class="draggable drag-drop"> Fire </div>
        <div id="act" class="draggable drag-drop"> Collapsed </div>    
    </div>
```

Comment: can you see your tab declaration code as well

Comment: updated accordingly :)

Comment: #danger not in code?

Comment: remove second active class from  <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade in ">